# "all the books I've read were written by her": the author either is dead or doesn't write books anymore?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, perfect-constructions

Does "all the books I've read were written by her" suggest that the author either is dead or doesn't write books anymore?

Answer (score 4):

No, it does not suggest that.  All of the books were written in the past, but it says nothing about the author.  We use *were written* only because the action of writing the books is in the past.